# Can a magnet-free motor do regenerative braking?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism

There are news talking about the new magnet-free motor for electrical vehicles from the manufacturer Mahle. They boast an efficiency of 96%.
Links:
[YouTube Video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY6TuVUxYQw)

My question is: Is a motor like that able to do regenerative braking?

Comment: On what alternative field to magnetism does the motor work?

Comment: Yes, it can! If you have an induction motor and you turn it faster than the nominal speed (defined by V/Hz), it becomes a generator and produces power.

Comment: Motors without magnets sort of precede the PMSM or BLDC. I mean, the original Tesla came up with this structure :)

Comment: It's important to note that "magnet free" does not mean "magnetism free"; the motor still uses magnetism, it just doesn't use permanent magnets. This makes the motor somewhat bulkier, but frequently cheaper (rare earth magnets are expensive) and can allow for some more advanced modes of control (such as a doubly-fed induction machine, useful for wind turbines for example).

Comment: @Hearth My bad, in my head the distinction between permanent magnets and electro magnets was there, when it really wasn't.

Comment: Every motor type can act as a generator, if excited correctly. This includes a Switched-Reluctance (no magnets) Machine and Squirrel-Cage inductance machines

Comment: Electrostatic motors, which don't use magnetism at all, *are* possible, but very impractical. You can't get any significant amount of torque out of them because the voltages required would just lead to arcing. However, some MEMS do use what you could call electrostatic motors.

Comment: And then you can talk about internal combustion engines and rocket engines, both of which are often called motors, and neither of which uses magnets in any facility other than control systems.

Comment: @Hearth: Electrostatic motors are not so impractical. They they can produce plenty of torque. They are limited in speed compared to electromagnetic motors because the rotor and stator are separated by a dielectric fluid gap rather than an air gap. The resulting drag limits the speed, but they are said to be competitive in the 100 - 2000 RPM range. https://www.c-motive.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The motor described is a wound-field synchronous motor with a brushless excitation system. It is basically the same machine as most large power station generators. Yes, it can provide regenerative braking.

The "new" aspect of this motor is said by the manufacture, [Mahle Gmbh](https://www.mahle.com/en/news-and-press/press-releases/mahle-develops-highly-efficient-magnet-free-electric-motor--82368), to be the excitation system. It is a wireless system that they have designed. The motor is being developed as a vehicle traction motor with the motor and controller integrated into a single housing. It appears to be a liquid cooled assembly.

Comment: Could you point me to a good resource, where I can read about the theoretical side of these types of motors and how to possibly implement regenerative braking with one? :)

Comment: Look for resources on "rotating machines".  This is not a new subject and the supposedly new motor looks an awful lot like motors in use since Thomas Edison's day.

Comment: If you click my name, you will find the names of three electric machinery text books. Here, you can find questions with the tags https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronous-motor, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generator, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternator, and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-machine that may be helpful.

Comment: @jwh: See addition to my answer re "new" aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating I am going to answer my own question here, because since people on this platform have helped me identify what I was really looking for, I have found a good source of information on a similar or maybe even identical motor design (Mahle GmbH does not disclose much, as far as I could find). So here goes my attempt to give back to the community.

For anybody else interested in this:

Here is the link to the publication:

[Publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7855023)

For the less fortunate who also lack access to that journal:

[This document was written by one of the authors of the paper above.](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1349258)

EDIT:
Section 12 here talks about using the motor as a generator, therefore I would at least conclude that regenerative braking should be possible, which merely confirms the more elaborate answers of the community.

Comment: You asked "Is a motor like that able to do regenerative braking?". So your answer is...?

Comment: I am aware of the excitation system. patented by Ludois & Hagen. It is capacitive rather than inductive. The Mahle images and statements pretty clearly indicate that they are using an inductive system. The Ludois & Hagen technology is available for license: warf.org/technologies/summary/P190295US01 –